# Python Sqlite3 passing BLOB to user-defined function gives None

Tags: python, sqlite, user-defined-functions

I am trying to pass the data from a `BLOB` column into a user defined function, but it shows up in that function as `None`. Is this just a quirk, or am I doing somethign wrong?

The `BLOB` data are jpegs I put into an `sqlite3` database using `Python 2.7.12`. The schema for the table is `CREATE TABLE data (md5sum TEXT PRIMARY KEY, data BLOB);`

---

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib


def p_data(x):
    print [x]
    return x

def p_md(x):
    print [x]
    return x

db=sqlite3.connect('tagged.db')
db.text_factory = str

db.create_function('P_DATA', 1, p_data)
db.create_function('P_MD', 1, p_md)

r = db.execute('SELECT P_MD(md5sum),P_DATA(data),data FROM data LIMIT 1')
for i in r:
    print
    # Don't want to print the thousands of bytes in i[-1]
    print i[:1]
    print hashlib.md5(i[-1]).hexdigest()

python test.py
[u'3040158ef2c323aaa63da499fc821d77']
[None]

('3040158ef2c323aaa63da499fc821d77', None)
3040158ef2c323aaa63da499fc821d77
```

## Edit

I boiled down my main program into the scripts below to make it easier to share an exact equivalent of what I am running. The test binary data (image) [is my avatar image](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4f880f29b27d5b2c14399512b7155f96?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG).

Easy initializer for `tagged.db`

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA writable_schema=ON;
INSERT INTO sqlite_master(type,name,tbl_name,rootpage,sql)VALUES('table','files','files',0,'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "files" USING fts3(fname TEXT, orig_name TEXT, tags TEXT, md5sum TEXT)');
CREATE TABLE 'files_content'(docid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'c0fname', 'c1orig_name', 'c2tags', 'c3md5sum');
CREATE TABLE 'files_segments'(blockid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, block BLOB);
CREATE TABLE 'files_segdir'(level INTEGER,idx INTEGER,start_block INTEGER,leaves_end_block INTEGER,end_block INTEGER,root BLOB,PRIMARY KEY(level, idx));
CREATE TABLE data (md5sum TEXT PRIMARY KEY, data BLOB);
CREATE INDEX idx1 on data(md5sum);
PRAGMA writable_schema=OFF;
COMMIT;
```

Contents of `test.py`

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib

def p_data(x):
    print 'inside p_data'
    print '\t', [x]
    return x

def p_md(x):
    print 'inside p_md'
    print '\t', [x]
    return x

db=sqlite3.connect('tagged.db')
db.text_factory = str

db.create_function('P_DATA', 1, p_data)
db.create_function('P_MD', 1, p_md)

fname = '4f880f29b27d5b2c14399512b7155f96.png'
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
md = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
db.execute('INSERT INTO files VALUES (?,?,?,?)', ('testname.png', fname, 'testtag', md))
db.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES (?,?)', (md, data))
# Don't commit so tagged.db will be empty each time test.py is started

r = db.execute('SELECT P_MD(md5sum),P_DATA(data),data FROM data LIMIT 1')
for i in r:
    print
    print i[:1]
    print hashlib.md5(i[-1]).hexdigest()

print
print 'Testing "SELECT typeof(data) FROM data LIMIT 1"'
r = db.execute('SELECT typeof(data) FROM data LIMIT 1')
print r.fetchone()

print
print 'Testing "SELECT p_data("Have some text")'
r = db.execute("SELECT p_data('Have some text')")
v = r.fetchone()
print v
print [str(v[0])]

print
print 'Testing "SELECT p_data(x\'112233\')"'
r = db.execute("SELECT p_data(x'112233')")
v = r.fetchone()
print v
```

Run `python test.py`

```
inside p_md
        [u'c337ae2a8ebd84b7e50240d875b2729e']
inside p_data
        [None]

('c337ae2a8ebd84b7e50240d875b2729e',)
c337ae2a8ebd84b7e50240d875b2729e

Testing "SELECT typeof(data) FROM data LIMIT 1"
('text',)

Testing "SELECT p_data("Have some text")
inside p_data
        [u'Have some text']
('Have some text',)
['Have some text']

Testing "SELECT p_data(x'112233')"
inside p_data
        [<read-write buffer ptr 0x7f31080cad18, size 3 at 0x7f31080cacd8>]
(<read-write buffer ptr 0x7f31080cad18, size 3 at 0x7f31080cacd8>,)
['\x11"3']
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. Are you completely certain that the `data` field for the returned row is not empty?

Comment: @peterdn Unfortuntely I am. I added a check to the above sample where I select the `data` column directly, and then hash it. For comparison the md5 of nothing is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this at all with python 2.7.13 and sqlite 3.16.0. Some ideas to investigate: what does `SELECT typeof(data) FROM data LIMIT 1` show? Does `p_data` still return `None` if you put text in the `data` field instead of a blob?

Comment: We cannot reproduce this without having the database. What is the output of `db.execute("SELECT p_data(x'112233')")`?

Comment: @peterdn `typeof(data` comes back as `text`. Passing text to `p_data` comes back as text (see edit).

Comment: @CL. The output of your exact statement is `'\x11"3'` (also added to edit above)

Comment: @chewsocks those edits have cleared things up, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `test.py` you'll find that `type(data)` is `str`, meaning it's inserted as text and likely getting confused about encoding when you read it back out.

The solution is to insert an `sqlite3.Binary` instead:

```py
db.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES (?,?)', (md, sqlite3.Binary(data)))
```

Comment: Thank you!! TBH I always never thought it made a difference since `str` and binary work together fine in most cases.

Comment: In case anyone else who reads this is interested, near the top (line 56 for me) of `dbapi2.py` (`sqlite3`'s source) defines `Binary = buffer`.